# Update data value via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to update  two data value.
 When I click on a div with class .messageconv grab the data-unread_mess_n value and subtract it from data-menutop_mess_nr and by the same data-unread_mess_n.
 
If the value of data-menutop_mess_nr==0 change the class.
I can't update data-unread_mess_n and data-menutop_mess values why?

```js
   

$(document).on('click touchstart', '.messageconv', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  messagesNumber($(this));

 });
function messagesNumber(elem) {
  var numMess = elem.parent().data('unread_mess_n');
  var numMessMenutop = $('#menutop_mess_nr').data('menutop_mess_nr');
  if (numMess != 0) {
   elem.children('p').remove();
  }
  var remainingMess = numMessMenutop - numMess;
  $('#menutop_mess_nr').html(remainingMess);
  if (remainingMess == 0) {
   $('#menutop_mess_nr').addClass('bluecount').removeClass('redcount');
  }
  elem.parent().data('unread_mess_n','0');
  $('#menutop_mess_nr').data('menutop_mess_nr',remainingMess);
  
 }
```

```css
 .messageconv{
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  
  }
 .redcount {
  background: #de2424;
  width:30px;
  }

 .bluecount {
  background: #333399;
  width:30px;
   }

  .redcount:hover {
   background: #ed4747;
   text-decoration: none;
   }
```

```html
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <a data-unread_mess_n="2" href="5">
 <div class="messageconv">
  test
 <p class="incmessage redcount">2</p></div>
 </a>
 <a data-unread_mess_n="3" href="4">
 <div class="messageconv">
 test1
 <p class="incmessage redcount">3</p></div>
 </a>
 <p data-menutop_mess_nr="5" id="menutop_mess_nr" class="incmessage redcount">5</p>
```

Comment: use `$('#menutop_mess_nr').attr('data-menutop_mess_nr',remainingMess);`

Comment: @guradio 10 very strange I see here my code works. If I add $('#menutop_mess_nr').attr('data-menutop_mess_nr',remainingM‌​ess); on my own complete code it crash

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
elem.parent().attr('unread_mess_n','0');
```